# How to disable a mode specified key-binding in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I installed [emmet-mode](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode).

The default key binding for `emmet-expand-line` is `C-j`.
But I want to use `C-i` for it. And `C-j` for `newline` function.

I can do with following elisp.

```
(define-key emmet-mode-keymap (kbd "C-i") 'emmet-expand-line)
(define-key emmet-mode-keymap (kbd "C-j") 'newline)
```

But if possible I don't want to use this "overwriting" way.
Is there way to "disable" a particular key binding in a mode?

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965966/unset-key-binding-in-emacs?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know.