# Emacs Unbind a Mode's KeyBinding

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs24, python-mode

I've created a custom key binding macro as follows:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-C C-c") "\C-a\C- \C-n\M-w\C-y")`

The problem is that `C-c C-c` is defined for `python-send-buffer` in `python-mode`. So my macro works for all modes except python-mode. I am assuming that `python-mode` is evaluated after my init file, so it overwrites that keybinding.

I tried unsetting `C-c C-c` using `(eval-after-load "python-mode")` and using `global-unset-key` but that doesn't work. `C-c C-c` in python is always mapping to `python-send-buffer`.

How can I completely disable Python's `C-c C-c`, and use my macro instead?

I am using Emacs 24.2.1.

Comment: C-c C-c is defined for a lot of modes.  Maybe you should consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Comment: Or just consider using a different key. `C-c` followed by a control key (such as `C-c`) is "reserved for major modes", meaning that Lisp code that defines a major mode is entitled to use it (and they often do use `C-c C-c`, as ScottFrazer said). Users are still entitled to bind such a key, of course, but just know that major modes will feel free to do so also, so you might need to then find a replacement key to use for such modes (see the answers here for that). See the Elisp manual, node `Key Binding Conventions`.

Comment: @Drew I can't seem to find a C-x binding that is free and easy to access/makes sense for doing this copy & paste which I use very often.

Comment: This question is a not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965966/unset-key-binding-in-emacs since the answers over there do not suggest using `add-hook`, but the OP states that they used `add-hook` and it did not work. Marking this question as a duplicate of that question is misleading. The answers for that question do not work in my case, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: @Darsky: Then don't use prefix `C-x` for this.  There are still plenty of keys available to you.  See the manual, `Key Binding Conventions` for which keys are reserved for users.  (And you can also bind any other keys, but they might override mode keys etc.) And you can define your own prefix keys: e.g., you can make `<f8>` be a prefix for some or all of your own keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (local-unset-key (kbd "C-c C-c"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") nil)))
```