# Emacs Minor Mode Sticky Control

Tags: emacs, minor-mode

Is there a minor mode in emacs that attaches a Control Key to every keystroke representing a single character? I wanted to get something similar to action mode in Vim. I've seen Viper, but would prefer not to spend the time to relearn all of the key-bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode

> This is a global minor mode for entering Emacs commands without modifier keys. It's similar to Vim's separation of commands and insertion mode.

The difference between this and viper/vimpulse/evil is that god-mode is still using the standard Emacs bindings.

It's not a direct answer<sup>1</sup> to your question, but I think it implements your actual end goal.

<sup>1</sup> This might be of some interest: [Software Requirements for Code Creation / Editor with RSI Type Symptoms (unusable fingers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802584/software-requirements-for-code-creation-editor-with-rsi-type-symptoms-unusabl/24804434#24804434)