# Emacs lisp: event-apply-super-key-modifier doesn't work

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm trying to use event-apply-super-key-modifier but I receive an error.
I mapped capslock as f13, with autohotkey; it works.
Now, I want to apply super modifier to f13 key with
`(global-set-key (kbd "<f13>") 'event-apply-super-key-modifier)`
So, when I press capslock, I receive:
Wrong type argument: commandp, event-apply-super-key-modifier.
I'm using emacs 25.1.1 maybe as changed use of this function?

If this is not possible to apply, I would use capslock key as modifier.
I can define prefix command to bind this key on a map.
My problem is that I want capslock key acts as a modifier only if it is pressed in conjunction with an other key. If it is pressed and released, I want an other behaviour.
Can I instruct emacs in this direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you, `event-apply-super-key-modifier` is not a command (and therefore cannot be bound to a key, because only commands may be bound to keys in a normal keymap).

You can still do what you want, though. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419718 regarding the special-purpose 'translation keymaps', and how you can write such a binding.